# How can I use different types of repeats in my lead sheet?

Tags: notation, repeats, lead-sheets

Happy Friday!

I'm trying to draft a lead sheet that captures the structure of a song I'm working on in a single page.  I just can't find a solution.  I hope to get better at notating repeats and creating lead sheets one day, but, for now, can you please assist?

The structure is as follows:

```
ABCACBD
```

As you'll see in my attempted road map, I got stuck because I didn't accommodate the BC/CB switch in the body of the song.

[image]

Any input is appreciated!  Thank you!!

Comment: Although the linked question is not an exact duplicate to your form, the techniques in the answers will solve the problem.

Comment: This is rather more complex than the linked question, and I think deserves an answer.   Here's a solution.  https://imgur.com/a/02uXipm  It also deserves a warning.   IF the lead sheet is purely for reference purposes, OK a complex repeat structure is acceptable.   But if there's any danger of musicians having to PLAY it - just don't.  Write it out.

Comment: Paper is cheap, rehearsal time is expensive. Write it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather more complex than the linked question, and I think deserves an answer. Here's a solution.

And here's an alternative solution.  Just notate each section once, in order ABCD.   Write over the top 'Play sections in this order: ABCACBD.'  Probably just as useful as a complex repeat structure.

(Those who use the score publisher Sibelius will recognise the two approaches.  Playback can be achieved with repeat barlines, DS al Coda instructions etc.  Or you can set up a manual playback map, instructing bars to be played in any arbitrary order.  Sometimes it's the only way.)

And my answer includes a warning. IF the lead sheet is purely for reference purposes, OK a complex repeat structure like this is acceptable. But if there's any danger of musicians having to READ and play it - just don't. Write it out.

[image]